# How to start SLIME in a full window from the command line

Tags: command-line-arguments, slime

I am looking for command-line solution for starting SLIME in a full window when starting Emacs. I need a command-line solution because I do not always want to start SLIME when starting Emacs (only sometimes).

This is the solution I am currently using:

```
emacs --eval '(let ((pop-up-windows nil)) (slime))'
```

It seems to work; it starts SLIME in a full window when starting Emacs. Since I am not an Emacs expert, I have no idea if it is appropriate or if there is a better way. Is there a better way?

Comment: How about putting a function in your `.emacs` / `init.el` file and calling just that from the command line instead of your let-bound statement?  E.g.,:  `(defun my-open-slime () (let ((pop-up-windows nil)) (slime)))`.  Or, perhaps set the value for `pop-up-windows` within your `.emacs` / `init.el` file for this behavior with everything by default:  `(setq pop-up-windows nil)`

Comment: @lawlist Is setting `pop-up-windows` to `nil` the proper way to do it? I don't want the behavior for everything, which is why I put it in a `let` instead of using `setq`.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to accomplish your goal of displaying the slime buffer so that it fills the entire frame.  The question as to whether there is a better way is a matter of opinion.  There is nothing wrong with the way in which you have done it.